# Field Length Always = 1

Tags: javascript, ajax

Following the [Reuters Ajax Solr tutorial](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki/Reuters-tutorial%3A-step-2) I'm having an issue getting a fields length.
The issue is with the 'template' but I believe it may stem from another js file.

THE TUTORIALS 'TEMPLATE'

```
template: function (doc) {
    var snippet = '';
    if (doc.text.length > 300) {
      snippet += doc.dateline + ' ' + doc.text.substring(0, 300);
      snippet += '<span style="display:none;">' + doc.text.substring(300);
      snippet += '</span> <a href="#" class="more">more</a>';
    }
    else {
      snippet += doc.dateline + ' ' + doc.text;
    }

    var output = '<div><h2>' + doc.title + '</h2>';
    output += '<p id="links_' + doc.id + '" class="links"></p>';
    output += '<p>' + snippet + '</p></div>';
    return output;
  },
```

MY 'TEMPLATE'

```
template: function (doc) {
    var snippet = '';
    if (doc.Solution.length > 200) {
            snippet += doc.Solution.substring(0, 200) + ' ' + doc.date;
            snippet += '<span style="display:none;">' + doc.Solution.substring(200);
            snippet += '</span> <a href="#" class="more">more</a>';
    }
    else {
        snippet += doc.Solution.length + '<br>' + doc.date + '';
    }
    var output = '<div><br><b>' + doc.Problem + '</b><br>';
    output += '' + snippet + '';
    output += ' ID #' + doc.id + '</div>';
    return output;
},
```

This section is supposed to allow for a 'more' button if a field is over a certain length. With my template, this is my output:

[image: output]

My 'Solution' field is a long text field which in my schema for solr (7.5) is defined as text_general.

I have tried `String()` and `.toString` but those gave me issues as well.

I'm very new to CS as a whole but it seems that my field is behaving as an array <s>or boolean?</s>
In the tutorial they have an older version of solr but the field they get the length on is text_general as well. I'm not exactly sure where I should look next.

PS: this is how the code is structured in the tutorial, a friend of mine was confused because it doesn't all seem to be best practices.

I my setup differs from the tutorial in a few ways, I use my version of JQuery (v3.3.1) and they use some style sheets that I do not.

The `<head>` of my html doc:

```
    <title>Testing Solr</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--style sheets and links in tutorial source code--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reuters.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <!--my downloaded copy of jquery-->
    <script src="script/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- mentioned in tutorial -->
    <script src="script/our.js"></script>
    <script src="script/Core.js"></script>
    <script src="script/AbstractManager.js"></script>
    <script src="script/Manager.jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script/Parameter.js"></script>
    <script src="script/ParameterStore.js"></script>
    <script src="script/AbstractWidget.js"></script>
    <script src="script/ResultWidget.js"></script>
```

Switched to using their links other than the reuters.css, still displaying  1.

Using `console.log(doc.Solution);` this is indeed acting as an array.

```
["solution to unlock    "]
0: "solution to unlock    "
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Adding `console.log(doc.text);` to the tutorial's ResultWidget.js returns plain text to the console. Whats a likely reason my field is being read as an array when theirs is read as a string?

Comment: so what is `doc.Solution`??  `console.log(doc.Solution)`

Comment: @epascarello thank you it does seem to be treating it as an array. ["solution to unlock    "]
0: "solution to unlock    "
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: @epascarello added the same to their ResultsWidget and plain text was returned.

Comment: @espascarello the issue is with my solr setup, some fields with json output are in quotes while others are in [ ]. Guessing the issue is with my schema